# Remove unused Vuetify CSS

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm looking for any configuration that can help with unused Vuetify CSS/JS code after build.
My current % of unused size is 99% (?)
[image]

is there any Vuetify configuration that can handle this by itself?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no auto fix yet. For some workaround, see https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/13724 and https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module/issues/382#issuecomment-761622329

Comment: i'll check those, thank you @AllanChain